# How to multiply by count of csv string in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have data like this:

```
[
  {
    "assetId": "12356464q,34rtyurt,56546b",
    "quantity": 1,
  },
  {
    "assetId": "84756e",
    "quantity": 5,
  },
  {
    "assetId": "vcxsr,820dds",
    "quantity": 4,
  },
]
```

I want to find the total number of quantities for every assetId summed. So in this case,  the total quantity will be `1*3 + 5*1 + 4*2 = 16`. How should the query be written?

Comment: Have you tried $split and $size?

Comment: @Joe How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$split` to split `assetId` by comma
- `$size` to get total elements from above split string
- `$multiply` actual `quantity` field and above total elements size
- `$group` by null and get the total quantity

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      quantity: {
        $multiply: [
          { $size: { $split: ["$assetId", ","] } },
          "$quantity"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalQuantity: {
        $sum: "$quantity"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/szDPgJgt3HU)